# Slidenav is not showing in UIkit 3 Beta with React, Do components need to be imported separately, how?

Tags: reactjs, meteor, getuikit

I am using UIKit 3 Beta in Meteor, ie with React. However my Slidenav icons

```
<a href="#" uk-slidenav-previous></a>
<a href="#" uk-slidenav-next></a>
```

are not showing. Do I need to import the components separately. If so how? Since I am working in Meteor UIkit is a node install. I do not see the components.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

The docs say:

> React will work with data-uk-* prefixes only.

https://getuikit.com/docs/javascript#uikit-and-reactive-javascript-frameworks

Try to change your attributes:

```
<a href="#" data-uk-slidenav-previous></a>
<a href="#" data-uk-slidenav-next></a>
```